# Is there a cross-platform way to convert SVG file to PNG at runtime?

Tags: java, svg, cross-platform

I need to convert SVG files to PNG files at first launch of a game and then save these PNG files to some assets folder. I'm wondering if i can achieve it on both Desktop and Android. The reason why i want to use SVG is to have resolution-independent assets at first and then convert them into PNG file with needed size according to user's screen resolution so there is no need to store multiple files per one asset. Is it possible to use one library or should i use different solutions for Desktop and Android? I'm using libGDX framework.

Note that i don't need to convert to PDF or using JavaScript as someone incorrectly decided.

Any other ways to achieve resolution independency will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i want to do it in Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Ah sorry.  The most developed java SVG renderer is Batik.  It can do what you want but is really only appropriate for desktop use.  I'm not sure whether anyone has got it working on Android.  However, there are SVG rendering libraries for Android.  My one - AndroidSVG - is IMHO the best of them.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau can you somehow unmark these question as duplicate?

Comment: I have voted to reopen it, but it still needs more votes before that happens.